Asymptotic density of strings generated by an (unambiguous) context-free grammar
Given an unambiguous context-free grammar $G$, I know there's a DP algorithm that efficiently computes the number of strings in $L(G)$ of length $n$.
However, I'm more interested in the asymptotics. Is there an efficient algorithm for determining the asymptotic behavior of $f(n) := $ "the number of strings in $L(G)$ with length at most $n$"? I'm looking for a simple asymptotic formula such as $f(n) = 2^{cn + O(\log n)}$ or $f(n) = 2^{cn\log n + o(n)}$ where $c$ can be computed from $G$.
My guess: $f(n) = 2^{cn + O(\log n)}$ for some $c \geq 0$. Is that true? If so, how do you compute $c$ given $G$?
I can write out a recursive formula for the number of strings in $L(G)$ with length exactly $n$ (i.e., the formula used in the DP algorithm I mentioned earlier). But I'm not sure how to analyze the asymptotics of the formula.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/225100/14578, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtzenberger_enumeration_theorem, https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=e3fc11ca227ab5edb6df5ce012f3934acfe57aa8.
